# What is Holika Dahan timings?

Tags: festivals

Holi is celebrated as a two day festival in India. The first day is known as Holika Dahan or Choti Holi and the second day is known as Rangon wali Holi.

Comment: The timings generally depend on the tithi and muhurat. They are not fixed and change every year.

Answer (score 4):

The muhurat for **Holika Dahan** generally depends on the tithi. It is not fixed and change every year. For example in 2018, the timings as given by **[Drik Panchang](https://www.drikpanchang.com/festivals/holi/festivals-holika-dahan-timings.html?year=2018)** were between 5:49 and 8:31 pm:

[image]

The **[muhurat for 2019](https://www.drikpanchang.com/festivals/holi/festivals-holika-dahan-timings.html)** starts at 8:27 pm and lasts till after midnight:

[image]